# Help in cleaning Code-39 Barcode data in Java

Tags: java, regex, barcode

I have a requirement to clean a string for illegal barcode-39 data and change each illegal charcter to whitespace. 
Currently the only valid characters in barcode-39 are 0-9,A-Z,-(dash),.(dot),$(dollar-sign),/(forward-slash),+(plus-sign),%(percent-sign)  and a space.

I tried the following regular expression but it seems to only use the not operator in the first group of characters.

```
barcode = barcode.toUpperCase().replaceAll("[^A-Z0-9\\s\\-\\.\\s\\$/\\+\\%]*"," ");
```

The code seems to only interpret, If not A to Z then replace with space. How do I make it interpret, if not A-Z and not 0-9 and not dash and not dollar-sign and not forward-slash, and so on, then replace char with a space.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your pattern string to `[^-0-9A-Z.$/+% ]`; this will match a single character that is not in the [Code 39](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Code_39) specification.  Also, if this is code that will get executed many times, avoid using `String.replaceAll()` since your pattern will get compiled for every method call.  Instead, use a pre-compiled pattern as follows:

```
final static Pattern INVALID_CODE39_CHAR = Pattern.compile("[^-0-9A-Z.$/+% ]");
barcode = INVALID_CODE39_CHAR.matcher(barcode.toUpperCase()).replaceAll(" ");
```

If you want to replace contiguous invalid characters with a single replacement string, add a `+` to the end of the pattern.  The `*` in your original pattern will match zero or more of the characters that are not in your character class; in effect, adding your replacement string,  (space), after all characters.

Take a look at the [Pattern](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) JavaDoc for more information; also, [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Why the "*" at the end? I would think that this isn't needed, and what's more will mess things up for you.

Comment: The * is state for any character that is not in the bracket. Do I need to place caret character on each group of letters?

Comment: `*` is not for any character not in the bracket. It's for multiple instances of characters in the bracket and will be "greedy". It adds extra spaces in your result String.