# Convert getJSONObject

Tags: java, android, json, code39

i want to change the output and input of `getJSONObject` i have tried using the following methods:

1. [Int to Float SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530209/convert-int-to-float) 
   2.[Int to String SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105331/how-to-convert-from-int-to-string) 
   3.[Int to Char SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114741/how-to-convert-int-to-char-c)

   ```
      JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(Integer.parseInt(Edittext)-1);
   ```

The function i am developing works as follows, someone enters a text, if the texts is in the jsonObject section of my json, the values which it contains are returned. The text or id, contains Code 39 coding, `0-9,A-Z,-(dash),.(dot),$(dollar-sign),/(forward-slash),+(plus-sign),%(percent-sign) and a space.` Resource: [Code 39 info SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439233/help-in-cleaning-code-39-barcode-data-in-java)
I thought the best way to make this possible was to try to change the jsonobject input and or output to chars..

Obviously i also need to change the `(Integer.parseInt(Edittext)-1);`

Is there a way? or am i just wasting my time here?? As the database im searching contains 20.000 values, i am not sure i can make use of `.ReplaceAll("value")`.

Thanks for any help i might receive.